# Transition of nested shared elements does not starts from the expected place

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

**TL;DR** Why this transition does not start from the expected place?

That is, the place where is the CardView.

[image]

**Platform/Deps:** Android Studio 1.0-RC2, TargetSdk 21, MinSdk 21, AppCompat-21.0.2, CardView-21.0.2, RecyclerView-21.0.2.

**Tested On:** Genymotion Nexus 5 Lollipop Preview

### The Code (Simplified)

I have three shared elements:

Source:

```
<CardView
    android:transitionName="cardView">
    <ImageView
      android:transitionName="imageView">
    <TextView
      android:transitionName="textView">
```

Target:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:transitionName="cardView">
    <ImageView
      android:transitionName="imageView">
    <TextView
      android:transitionName="textView">
```

Note below that the transition names are added programmatically. This is because CardView are holded on a RecyclerView and there are many copies of it. I've tried using the same name (as in the XML instance) but doesn't work neither.

The ReciclerView.Adapter does this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    //...
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(viewHolder.mCardView, "cardViewTransition" + position);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(viewHolder.mImageView, "imageTransition" + position);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(viewHolder.mTextView, "textTransition" + position);
    //...
}
```

The HomeActivity does this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
    // ..
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
        new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(selfContext, DetailActivity.class);

                View imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putInt("position", position);
                extras.putString("text", textView.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                String name = ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view);
                ActivityOptionsCompat options =
                    ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(selfContext
                            ,Pair.create(view, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view))
                            ,Pair.create(imageView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView))
                            ,Pair.create((View)textView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(textView))
                    );
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(selfContext, intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        })
    );
    ///...
}
```

The DetailActivity does this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    // ...

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int mPositionRef = extras.getInt("position");
    View base = findViewById(R.id.detail_layout);
    View image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);
    text.setText(extras.getString("text"));

    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(base, "cardViewTransition" + mPositionRef);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(image, "imageTransition" + mPositionRef);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(text, "textTransition" + mPositionRef);

}
```

I've debugged and shared elements have the same names in the source and destination.

### The Question (Again)

Why this transition does not start from the expected place? That is, the place where is the CardView.

Complete sample in [GitHub](https://github.com/rnrneverdies/HeroTransition)

Comment: There is a known bug in Lollipop related to nested shared elements (i.e. adding both a view group and one of its children as shared elements at the same time), so it might be related to that (source: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26495077/844882).

Comment: Try only adding the `ImageView` and `TextView` as shared elements instead (not the parent relative layout container).

Comment: @AlexLockwood YES! Today you're my Hero.

Comment: Well, sounds like that answer worked for you. :) I'll add it as an answer instead of a comment... unless you have any other questions.

Comment: Also, nice "Hero" pun. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug in Lollipop related to nested shared elements (i.e. adding both a view group and one of its children as shared elements at the same time), so it might be related to that (source: [Glitch when animating nested views in a shared element Activity transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495077)).

Try only adding the ImageView and TextView as shared elements instead (not the parent relative layout container).

Comment: adding the ImageView and TextView as shared elements still giving the same issue. Any Help plz

Answer (score 0):

It could be that all the items have the exact same transition because they all use the same name. You can use the method in this tutorial (https://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/index.html) to set a unique transition name programmatically in onBindViewHolder():

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(
    holder.mySharedView, 
    "item_" + String.valueOf(sharedItem.getId()
);
```