# Fragment shared element transition not working in nested views

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

I have a strange problem (maybe it's a bug in transitions library) with shared element transition animations. Target `Android version` is `5.0`.

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- The main content view -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
            </FrameLayout>

            <!-- The second content view -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_second"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have 2 fragments (`FragmentA` and `FragmentB`). `FragmentA` has `imageViewA` and `FragmentB` has `imageViewA` with bigger size. Shared element transitions defined correctly and when `FragmentB` opens `imageViewA` animated correctly.

**But** it works just in case when `FragmentA` is added to `content_frame` container (root container). If I'm adding `FragmentA` to `content_main` container - animation not working at all.

- If I add to `content_second` container some view - animation is not working.
- If I keep `content_second` container empty - animation is not working.
- Even if I remove `content_second` container - animation is not working.

Both fragments would be added to the same container (using `FragmentTransaction.replace`).

Comment: What version of Android are you running on? (5.0 or 5.1?) There is at least one bug regarding nested shared element views in 5.0, which is why I ask. See this SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26495077/844882) for more info.

Comment: 5.0.2 :( but the following link tells about bug with Activity transitions. Is it true for Fragment's also?