# Shared Element Transitions not working when exit from fragment to Activity containing Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

I have a `RecyclerView` inside the fragment in a Viewpager and sharing element from an item in the `RecyclerView` to a `DetailActivity` containing a fragment. I am setting transition inside the `DetailActivity` for the entry and exit of the fragment.

```
public static void sharedTransitionReceiver(Activity activity, Fragment fragment) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        activity.getWindow().getEnterTransition().setDuration(500);
        Slide slideTransition = new Slide(Gravity.START);
        slideTransition.setDuration(500);
        fragment.setReenterTransition(slideTransition);
        fragment.setExitTransition(slideTransition);
        fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new ChangeBounds());
    }
}
```

It is working just fine but when I navigate back to the previous activity containing the Viewpager exit animations are not working and item won't animates back to their original position.

Comment: Call setSharedElementReturnTransition() to specify how the View moves from the second Fragment back to the first Fragment when the user hits the back button.

Comment: No use it is stil the same.

Comment: @BurakCakir As per the docs return animation is the reverse of entry animation by default.

Comment: you're right mate. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31123697/5392118) solved my transition problem with viewpager, hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 4 hours of effort, I cannot imagine the answer to be that simple. I was calling `finish()` after popping out every fragment from stack instead I have to use `supportFinishAfterTransition();`.

Comment: can you guide me how to perform fragment to activity shared element Transitions ?

Comment: How to use this if there is a exit transition from fragment to another fragment?